# What do "as" and parentheses do in SQL queries?

Tags: php, database

I'm working on a function where the users on my site will be able to message one another. I looked up how to do this and found code that was available to download and am now using that. I understand what most of it means, and I'm plugging in my own variables and deciphering it, but I found a SELECT function to the database I'd never seen before.

```
//We check if the recipient exists

$dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, 
(select count(*) from pm) as npm from Users where username="'.$recip.'"'));
```

I've seen SELECT functions, but never where it uses the word `as`, or parentheses. Can someone tell me what exactly these things are doing? Is it setting them as variables or something? This is the only line of code that is causing problems.

Comment: Yes, all those "as X" are called "aliases". The second "select" within the main "select" is called a subquery and it's returning the total value from the table `pm` and assigning it to the alias `npm`.

Answer (score 1):

So basically what that line does is

1. **count(id) as recip** : counts the total of rows (just using the column ID for it) and assign that value to the alias `recip`
2. **id as recipid** : assign id to `recipid`
3. **(select count(*) from pm) as npm** : It does a subquery which returns the count of rows from the table `pm` and assign it to `npm`.

All this relative to the condition specified in the clause **WHERE**

Check this for **ALIASES**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

And this one for **SUBQUERIES**
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a breakdown:

```
select count(id) as recip
```

Selecting the rowcount of the yet to be declared table and assigning it the alias of 'recip'

```
id as recipid
```

Assigning the id column an alias of recipid

```
(select count(*) from pm) as npm
```

Subquery to select rowcount of pm table and assign it the alias of npm

```
from Users where username="'.$recip.'"'
```

Specifying the table to query and the condition. (where username column = the value of $recip)